# Problem with OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

I use QGIS in my daily work, but since a few months back I'm unable to do this due the OpenLayers plugin no longer being functional. When I try to load a background map nothing happen - the canvas remains white. I have tried it on several computers and the same problem occurs. I use the latest version of QGIS (Lyon).

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: The question is whether there are more of you having the same problem and what the solution might be.

Comment: The advice offered in that thread solved my problem! Thank you for the help!